# Tridion 2013 file name too large error while publishing

Tags: 2013, publishing, deployer

While publishing the pages in Tridion 2013 publishing fails

> Error details : The specified path, file name, or both are too long.
>   The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and
>   the directory name must be less than 248 characters

.

Is there any way we can increase the character limits??

Comment: I am facing the same error in a Tridion 2011 environment. I have read the post mentioned, but am still struggling to understand what to update to overcome this error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Judging by the previous answer... It looks like you need to make sure the path you're deploying to is within the windows limit

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/2380)

Answer (score 11):

It is actually a windows path limitations and error comes from it

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#maxpath